# Is it not anymore necessary to enclose the values of attributes in HTML5 with quotes?

Tags: html

I am trying to learn HTML5 and I saw some tutorials that do something like:

```
<input type=email>
```

And I noticed that it differs from XHTML where most values (if not all) should be enclosed in quotes.

Will this have any future things that I have to take caution of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll refer you to the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0

> Attributes can be specified in four different ways:
>
> - Empty attribute syntax
> - Unquoted attribute value syntax
> - Single-quoted attribute value syntax
> - Double-quoted attribute value syntax

Answer (score 1):

HTML has never required quoting attribute values (it is optional). XHTML has always required quoted attribute values. HTML5 carries on this tradition.