# Newly added elements using jQuery doesn't have it's CSS applied correctly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use jQuery to dynamically add new elements. But the newly added element doesn't have it's CSS applied properly.

I have demonstrated my problem with the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Mzs2/14/). The newly added input text box has different spacing between them.

HTML Code:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="control-group custom">
        <label class="input-mini" for="first">Start</label>
        <label class="input-mini" for="first">End</label>
        <label class="input-mini" for="first">Share</label>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group custom">
        <input type="text" class="input-mini">
        <input type="text" class="input-mini">
        <input type="text" class="input-mini">
    </div>
    <div>   
     <a id="plus_time_button" class="btn plus" href="#">
      <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
     </a>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

JS Code:

```
 $("#plus_time_button").live("click", function () {
    var new_row = "<div class=\"control-group custom\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"input-mini\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"input-mini\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"input-mini\"></div><div><a id=\"plus_time_button\" class=\"btn plus\" href=\"#\"><i class=\"icon-plus-sign\"></i></a></div>";
    $("fieldset div:last-child").remove();
    $("fieldset").append(new_row);
});
```

CSS Code:

```
.custom label {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center !important;
}
.custom input {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

There is a somewhat [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249250/jqm-jquerymobile-dynamically-added-elements-not-displaying-correctly-and-css-i) but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces.

Your original HTML uses code like this:

```
<input ...>
<input ...>
```

Your added HTML uses code like this:

```
<input ...><input ...>
```

The whitespace between tags in the first results in a little extra space (the... size of a space) between tags, which the added rows lack.

A couple strategies:

Broadly, you can avoid annoying whitespace interference like this like so:

```
<input type=text class=input-mini
><input type=text ...
```

The trailing angle bracket wraps to the next line to consume all the whitespace.

But, what you really ought to be doing here is reusing the same DOM elements in the added rows as you use in the originals, so there's no difference row to row.

An approach I often use:

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/3Mzs2/17/

Create a single row template - I like to use an id of "T":

```
<div id=T class="control-group custom">
  <input type=text class=input-mini>
  <input type=text class=input-mini>
  <input type=text class=input-mini>
</div>
```

Get the template row and remove its id, then just clone it whenever you need to add one - that way whatever HTML you happened to use in the original, gets reused in your appends:

```
var plus = $('#plus_time_button').closest('div');
var T = $('#T');
T[0].id = '';

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    plus.before(T.clone());

$('#plus_time_button').click(function () {
    plus.before(T.clone());
});
```

My original answer used your existing event syntax, with .live(). Converting to the jQuery 1.9 syntax isn't necessary since you're presumably still on 1.7 or 1.8, but if you'd like, the code above does away with live (it actually discards it entirely since it isn't necessary any longer - the tag in question is never removed from the DOM). Examples for converting .live() calls for 1.9 are provided in the jQuery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/live/#entry-longdesc

Comment: `.live` has been deprecated. Use `.on`

Comment: @hitautodestruct Agreed - actually neither .on nor .live are even necessary here - .click is not deprecated, shorter, and all that's needed here since the add row is never removed in this approach. Updated to discard .live() entirely.

Comment: It looks like someone proposed an edit where they quote a bunch of attribute values here - those are not necessary, neither in browsers in use today nor the HTML5 spec. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816233/is-it-not-anymore-necessary-to-enclose-the-values-of-attributes-in-html5-with-qu

Answer (score 1):

*moved `plus_time_button` outside of fieldset*

```
$("#plus_time_button").live("click", function () {
    $("fieldset").find('div:last').clone().appendTo('fieldset');
    //scrollToBottom("create_table");
});
```

working Fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/SSPRJ/

Answer (score 1):

You have to put some space between the inputs, so i have added "`&nbsp`" between your inputs

```
$("#plus_time_button").live("click", function () {
    var new_row = "<div class=\"control-group custom\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"input-mini\">&nbsp<input type=\"text\" class=\"input-mini\">&nbsp<input type=\"text\" class=\"input-mini\"></div><div><a id=\"plus_time_button\" class=\"btn plus\" href=\"#\"><i class=\"icon-plus-sign\"></i></a></div>";
    $("fieldset div:last-child").remove();
    $("fieldset").append(new_row);
    scrollToBottom("create_table");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/3Mzs2/16/)

Answer (score 1):

The browser is accounting for the spaces in your initial HTML.

### Quick answer

<kbd>**[Heres a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Mzs2/18/)**</kbd>

Remove the spaces in your initial HTML:

```
...
<input type="text" class="input-mini">
<input type="text" class="input-mini">
...
```

The above two lines are separated by a [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) which the browser interprets as a physical space.

Keep your elements without any space in them:

```
<input type="text" class="input-mini"><input type="text" class="input-mini">
```

### Why?

Since you are using `display: inline-block` the browser is also applying the rules that it uses to interpret text and as such respects the space between your html elements.

When you're outputting the dynamic elements using javascript the concatenation of strings does not include a space.

You could also use:

```
.custom label {
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.custom label:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this for my accordion, after append a new node, with

`$('#accordion').accordion( "refresh" );`